# How to make sure playwright closed all instances of browser?

Tags: continuous-integration, playwright-java

Sometimes my test page goes unresponsive and we restart whole framework. As a part of it we restart playwright browser. We shut it down like:

```
    fun close() {
        context.pages().forEach{
            log.info("closing page ${it.title()}")
            it.close()
        }
        log.info("closing context")
        context.close()
        log.info("closing playwright")
        playwright.close()
    }
```

But anyway sometimes browser don't close and I can see multiple instances of firefox running. I know I can use some variation of`system.exec('pkill firefox')` but I would prefer closing it from java/kotlin directly.

btw. can I get pid of firefox root process? Usually i can see 4-5 firefox processes (I use 2 tabs).